# jQuery ToDo list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I work on the simple ToDo list written on jQuery (and JS, of course). 
I already created the static ToDo list with a possibility to add new items only by editing the code. It is logically that I am going to create a dynamic list now.

I've already tried some methods, like .load() code from external file, create .after(), but it all goes wrong for me.

What would you suggest me to do?

You may find all the source codes in [strasbourgmeetings.org/ccc](http://www.strasbourgmeetings.org/ccc)

I would be very grateful if you could help me solving this question.

***Gloserio***, yes, Add Item does not work now, because I of the problem I described.

***ncubica***, the problem is that at the moment I am not able to add new items to my list (only bu editing the code). Dynamic means that it would be possible to add/delete items. To do that I tried to use `.after()` method with the function inside it, that will copy the `<li id="item1">List item here</li><li id="buttons1">Buttons here</li>` (roughly speaking), but it puts all list items on the upper side and all buttons to the bottom.

This is a part of the JS code:

```
        <script>
    // Waiting for the document to load
        $(document).ready(function() {
    // Wanted to create a dynamic item list, that's why I used this variable. I thought it would
    // generate unique IDs (there was 'id++' somewhere in the function I already deleted).
            var id = 1;

    // This is going to be used as an action for 'Add Item' button. (It is not a button, actually, it is just <span> with cursor: pointer. Using <a> causes page reload);
            $('.add').click(function() {
                $('#item'+id).after(function(i) { // '#item'+id should be something like this in the code: #item2, #item3, etc.

                })
            })

    // 'Done' button
            $('#done1').click(function() {
                console.log('# "Done" button pressed');
                $('#list1').css('background-color','#89f49a').css('border','1px solid #16bf31').css('text-decoration','line-through').css('color','#817f7f').css('font-weight','normal');
                console.log('# Item doned successfully');
            });

    // 'Undone' button (is gonna be renamed to 'Reset');
            $('#undone1').click(function() {
                console.log('# "Undone" button pressed');
                $('#list1').css('background-color','').css('border','').css('text-decoration','').css('color','').css('font-weight','normal');
            });

    // 'Working' button
            $('#working1').click(function() {
                $('#list1').css('background-color','#edc951').css('border','1px solid #dda119').css('font-weight','bold').css('color','#000').css('text-decoration','none');
            });

    // 'Cancel' button
            $('#cancel1').click(function() {
                $('#list1').css('background-color','#ff8c8c').css('border','1px solid #ea2c2c').css('font-weight','normal').css('text-decoration','line-through').css('color','#f00');
            });
    // 'Delete' button
            $('#del1').click(function() {
                $('div#dlist1').remove();
                $('li#action1').remove();
            });
        });
    </script>
```

And HTML part:

```
<div class="list">
                        <ul id="sortable">
                            <div class="list-item" id="item1"><div class="spacer1" id="spacer1"></div>
                            <div class="l-element" id="dlist1"><li id="list1" class="ui-widget ui-state-default">Create add feature</div>
                            <li id="action1" class="action"><input type="button" value="Done" class="done" id="done1"><input type="button" value="Undone" class="undone" id="undone1"><input type="button" value="Working" class="working" id="working1"><input type="button" value="Cancel" class="cancel" id="cancel1"><span id="del1" class="delete">Delete</span></li>
                            <div class="spacer"></div></div>
                        </ul>
                    <div>
```

As you can see, there is only 1 list item I wrote. IDs are static and can not be changed at the moment. All I need is to change IDs (ok, it will be var id = 1; id++) and to add the part of the code (inside `<div class="list-item"`)

Comment: Clicking on `add item`, it does nothing, is that normal ? Few questions : what do you mean by dynamic ? And where does your current problem lie ?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you problem is.. please show some code and we can help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why don't you try jQuery's .clone() and attach it to the "Add Item" behaviour?

You can check it [here](http://api.jquery.com/clone/).

Comment: Thanks a lot! I totally forgot about .clone() method.
It creates new elements, but, unfortunately, any button does not work with the created element. It is logically, just because it is related with the id, but even 
$('#undone' + id).click(function() { ...
does not solve the newly created problem :(

Comment: Are you sure of that?
I just tried your example at [link](http://www.strasbourgmeetings.org/ccc) and it seems to work.

Comment: Nope, actually. Just tried this code with some improvements and it worked. Thanks a lot! My fault...

Answer (score 1):

I personally made one as well, and it works really simply, a checkbox, the text, followed by a delete button.
Works great, though I'm still working on a way to make it save it after you close the browser.

jQuery code:

```
function addListItem() {
    var textToAdd = $('#new-text').val();                    // The finish class is just for css styling
    $('#list').append('<li class="item"><input type="checkbox" class="finish" />' + textToAdd + '<button class="delete">Delete</button></li>');
    $('#new-text').val('');
}

function deleteItem() {
    $(this).parent().remove();
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#add').on('click', addListItem);
    $(document).on('click', '.delete', deleteItem);
});
```

HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>To Do List</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    </head>
    <body>

        <h2>To Do List</h2>
        <p>Project started on <strong>4-1-2015</strong>.</p>

        <input type="text" id="new-text" /><button id="add">Add</button>

        <ul id="list">

        </ul>

        <script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Hope this helped :)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. 
Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.